# Draw olympic circles. Java ME does not support certain imports! Please help

Tags: java, java-me

Hello i am trying to draw an olympic symbol into my screen for my mobile app. I know how to do it in java applet. Im not able to do in java ME. Please help.

Since the packages

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.applet.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
```

Is not supported by java ME. T
The follwing code to draw the olympic symbol works for java. But does not work for java ME

```
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
    //Draw the First Circle and make it red 
    g.drawOval (1,0,40,40); g.setColor(Color.red);

    //Draw the Second Circle and make it blue
    g.drawOval (21,20,40,40);g.setColor(Color.blue);

    //Draw the Third Circle and make it yellow
    g.drawOval (41,0,40,40);g.setColor(Color.yellow);

    //Draw the Fourth Circle and make it black
    g.drawOval (61,20,40,40);g.setColor(Color.black);

    //Draw the Fifth Circle and make it green
    g.drawOval (81,0,40,40);g.setColor(Color.green);
    }
```

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 3):

AWT and Applets aren't available for Java ME. Due to the screen size limitations and restricted user interactions, the MIDP UI API is designed for mobile devices comprising of the high level and low level UI. Look at [Java ME documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html).

You can use [Canvas](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/gameapi/) and draw the circle. Refer more info look at following links,

- [MIDP GUI Programming: Programming the Phone Interface](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/ui/)
- [MIDP user interface](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2005/jw-0516-midp.html)
- [MIDP Programming with J2ME](http://www.developer.com/java/j2me/article.php/10934_1561591_1)

**FYI:** You can use [LWUIT framework.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152237/what-is-lwuit-light-weight-user-interface-toolkit) LWUIT provides many useful Swing-like features.